# Android - Listview items change background when selected (checkable)

Tags: android, listview

How can I make a `ListView` item changed its background when pressed, like it was checked but no checkbox, I know it has a `checkListener` or something but i don't know how to apply. Remain its color background after pressed and changed back to its first background when pressed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create `boolean` field in your `Model-Class`.
2) Define root `Layout` of item (create `id` and find view in `ListView` `Adapter's` `getView()` method).
3) Add `OnClickListener` for root `Layout`, if clicked new `boolean` = true.
4) If new `boolean` of your `Model-Class` item is true, set root `Layout` bg_color_1, else set bg_color_2.

Answer (score 2):

Your `listItem.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your selector: `listview_selector.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_default"/>

</selector>
```

Your Layout with listivew:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewMainFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector.xml"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is `android:state_activated` attribute inside item?

Answer (score 1):

> Try this

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    });
```

Comment: other items inside my list also becomes green before I pressed them,